# What are the various constructor calls in this code?

Tags: c++, constructor, move

```
struct custom
{
  custom();
  custom(const custom &);
  custom(custom &&);
};

custom find()
{
  return custom();
}

void take(const custom &c)
{
  custom temp = t;
}

void take(custom &&c)
{
  custom temp = std::move(c);
}
```

How many calls to the constructors of `custom` are made and in what order by the following:

```
custom first = find();
take(first);

custom second = find();
take(std::move(second));
```

The first `find()` call just uses the default constructor. The first `take` call uses the copy constructor I believe. Second `find()` call also just uses the default constructor. I am not certain of the second `take` call. I believe it uses the move constructor here. Is that correct? If so, the sequence of constructor calls is default, copy, default, move (in this order)?

Comment: You could simply add logging in the constructors and then you would see the sequences for yourself. [Demo](https://ideone.com/a19kOr)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did and it seems to confirm what I wrote in the OP, but I am a bit confused now why, e.g., the first `find()` call does not invoke the move constructor. The res of the first `find()` call is an r-value, so shouldn't it get moved into the variable `first`?

Comment: "*the first find() call does not invoke the move constructor"* - correct, because nothing is being moved. "*The res of the first find() call is an r-value, so shouldn't it get moved into the variable first?*" - no. Read up on ["Copy Elison"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (also known as "Return Value Optimization").

Comment: Have a look here: [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have read that before but my impression of that is it's platform dependent? Are you saying in this case the move will never be called and copy elison will always be done?

Comment: @user5965026 "*I have read that before but my impression of that is it's platform dependent?*" - once upon a time, but not anymore, it is now required standard behavior since C++17. "*Are you saying in this case the move will never be called and copy elison will always be done?*" - in modern C++, yes. The standard guarantees it.

Comment: @user5965026  Note that there is a difference in asking "What are the various constructor calls in this code?" and "How many calls to the constructors of custom are made".  You have 3 different user-defined constructors -- default, copy, and move constructor.  That is a given,  That is totally different than asking "what gets called when".